# Ruby: uncompress zlib-wrapped deflate data

Tags: ruby, zlib

In Ruby, I have a buffer containing data compressed with the zlib `compress2()` method. However I found no way to decompress this data using the Zlib functionality in the Ruby standard library which only supports data created by `deflate` or data in GZip format.

How can I achieve the equivalent of `uncompress()` in Ruby, preferably without resorting to creating a custom C-extension?

Edit:

I found the solution. After fiddling around with the `window_bits` argument to the `Inflate` constructor without success, I finally understood that zlib prefixes the compressed data with a four-byte header. So I simply removed that header and suddenly it worked like a charm:

```
  data[0..3] = ''
  data = Zlib::Inflate.inflate(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/Zlib/Inflate.html) indicates that the Ruby inflate class will decompress the output of compress2(), which is in the zlib format.  I just tried it, and it works fine.  Your compressed data may not be making it over to Ruby intact.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it is indeed supported. I couldn't get the `Inflate` class to work without modifying my input data but it was really helpful to know that it should work :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use negative value for `window_bits` as stated [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/Zlib/Inflate.html#method-c-new). I've faced similar problem but for compressing on Ruby and decompressing on JS ([my gist for that](https://gist.github.com/alazarchuk/8223772181741c4b7a7c)). Hope it helps to avoid magic with four bites :)